# How to use Custom Authorization with Cookie Session and local DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I'm not using any default ASP.NET MVC Authorization, so I create my own Authorization a cookie & session to my project for my security. This code below is my function Login that the first time cookie and session generated.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
    bool ValidEmail = db.Users.Any(u => u.Username == user.Username);

    if (!ValidEmail)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }

    string Password = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username == user.Username).Select(u => u.Password).Single();
    user.Password = GenerateHashPassword(user.Password);

    if (Password != user.Password)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }

    string AuthID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session["AuthID"] = AuthID;
    var Cookie = new HttpCookie("AuthID");
    Cookie.Values["AuthID"] = AuthID;
    Cookie.Values["Username"] = user.Username;
    Cookie.Values["LastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
    Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Course");
}
```

My User model is:

```
public class User
{
     public string UserID { get; set; }
     public string Username { get; set; }
     public string Password [ get; set; }
}
```

Once after user logged in, the user has some privilleges to the `CourseController`, `HomeworkController`, `ExamController`. My current authorization is using `if-statement` to each function inside those controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["AuthID"].Values["AuthID"] == Session["AuthID"].ToString())
        {
             // main code here ... 
        }
        else
        {
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

I want to secure those controller with something like the default ASP.NET Authorization, that is **[Authorization]**. This will wrap it up all of those if-statements by only placing it on top of the controller code.

How am I supposed to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what filters are for. In particular, for MVC controllers, you want to create your own Authorization Attribute which will inherit from AuthorizeAttribute and then implement your own logic in there. Your own logic, in this case, is what you have in if statements in your controller methods at the moment.

Example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/